# Tree view is getting wrapped

Tags: javascript, html, css, treeview

The tree view is getting wrapped when you resize the window.

In Bootstrap, the table does not shrink on window resize but a horizontal scroll bar becomes visible which can be used to scroll the table to see it.

How can it be made like the Bootstrap 4 responsive table? So that on window resize the tree view does not shrink and a horizontal scroll bar becomes visible to scroll and view the full tree view.

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-tranasition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#">1</a>
   <ul>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li><li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">3</a>
     <ul>
      <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">3.1</a>
              <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">3.1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">3.1.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">3.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried applying a fixed width (IE: not a %) to the tree container? You could then have whatever dom element that container lived in have a responsive width with `overflow: scroll`

Comment: @Jacquesジャック Tried still for working, then I also tried the below answer and it kind of worked but the tree view is going out of the container div and the horizontal scroll bar is visible all the time.

Comment: What do you mean it's `going out of the container div`? It wouldn't be scrollable otherwise. Also, if you want the scrollbar gone, that's a separate issue. https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/scrollable-fixed-div-but-hide-scrollbars/

Answer (score 1):

As a quick example, I added a container around the `.tree` element, and gave it a `width: 100%` and `overflow: scroll`. Then I set `.tree` to have a static width. Seems to work fine.

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.tree { width: 1000px; } /* ******* I added this ******* */
.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-tranasition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
.tree-cont { width: 100%; overflow: scroll; }
```

```html
<div class="tree-cont"> <!-- added this wrapper -->
<div class="tree">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#">1</a>
   <ul>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li><li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">3</a>
     <ul>
      <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">3.1</a>
              <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">3.1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">3.1.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">3.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check snippet.

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.tree{
width:100%;
overflow-x:scroll;
}
.scrollwidth{width:900px;}
.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-tranasition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
 <ul class="scrollwidth">
  <li>
   <a href="#">1</a>
   <ul>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li><li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">3</a>
     <ul>
      <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">3.1</a>
              <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">3.1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">3.1.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">3.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check snippet.

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.tree{width:100%;overflow-x:scroll;}
.scrollwidth{width:900px;}
.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-tranasition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
 <ul class="scrollwidth">
  <li>
   <a href="#">1</a>
   <ul>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li><li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">2</a>
     <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">2.1</a>
              
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">3</a>
     <ul>
      <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">3.1</a>
              <ul>
            <li>
       <a href="#">3.1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">3.1.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">3.2</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```